# Software to insert note in all files for GNU

Tags: text-editors

I've developed a software and want to submit it in GNU.
But for that i need to insert GNU notice in all the files.
Is there any free software to do this job [inserting a common note to all file ] ?

Comment: You might be mixing GNU and GPL. I assume you want to add a GPL license header to every file. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's called `cat`.

```
cat notice.txt origfile.txt > newfile.txt && mv newfile.txt origfile.txt
```

Comment: i've lots of PHP files, and I've Ubuntu 11.04, guide me

Comment: If these are PHP, this implies that you know PHP. You should be able to write a simple script to go trough all the files and use the "cat" command.

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
for i in `find . -type f` ; do
  cat notice.txt $i > $i.new && mv $i.new $i
done
```

You probably want to back up your tree before you run this.